# how to remove the listening of callback on anonymous method?

Tags: c#

I wrote some class:

```
public class A 
{
    public A()
    {
        serviceAdapter.CompletedCallBackEvent += new EventHandler( foo );
        .
        .
        .
    }

    void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serviceAdapter.CompletedCallBackEvent -= new EventHandler( foo );
    }
}
```

Now, i want to change this callback listener with some anonymous - but i don't know how to remove the callback listener in the anonymous method .

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
            serviceAdapter.CompletedCallBackEvent += delegate( object sender, EventArgs ee )
            {
                  ... need to remove the listener to the event. 
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply assign your delegate/handler to a private variable.

```
private EventHander _handler = null;

public A()
{        
    _handler = delegate( object sender, EventArgs ee)
        {          
            ServiceAdapter.CompletedCallBackEvent -= _handler;
        };
    ServiceAdapter.CompletedCallBackEvent += _handler;
}
```

Comment: How can you assign the delegate to private variable ? i trying and its not working ( not compile )

Comment: @Yanshof: You can create a private variable in your class of type EventHandler instead of the CompletedCallBackEventHandler I mentioned above, (it's kind of pseudocode)... Could you also mention what kind of error your are getting? Am assuming this is the error on "CompletedCallBackEventHandler" You also assign this private variable in your method/constructor

Comment: i wrote it as you did - and its not compile

Comment: The error is fairly obvious, something along the lines of `_handler is not declared...`

Comment: @Hasanain, your edit does not fix the problem. You cannot use a local variable from `A()` in `Dispose`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, yeah I just saw that edited trying to fix it when I saw the Yanshof's question, I obviously screwed up the edit further... now fixed...

Comment: @Hasanain: While your code works, I can't remove my -1 because @Yanshof wants the event handler removed *when it fires* (run once semantics) while your answer requires `IDisposable` implementation and potentially allows the event to be run multiple times prior to disposal.

Comment: @Hasanain: My apologies, didn't notice the edit. Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove the anonymous delegate like that.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article on anonymous delegates.  Also worth reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/04/688527.aspx)

You may be able to do:

```
     public A()
     {
         EventHandler myHandler = null;
         myHandler = new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs e)
             {
                 serviceAdapter.CompletedCallbackEvent -= myHandler;
             });

         serviceAdapter.CompletedCallBackEvent += myHandler;
     }
```

Comment: I've fixed up `myEvent` to be `serviceAdapter.CompletedCallbackEvent` so that this could be +1'd.

Comment: No problem sir, looked like a copy/paste omission.